# How to compare all columns of all tables from two databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two databases. One is for transaction purposes and another is for auditing purposes. The database names are `CLX_DEVELOPMENT` and `CLX_DEVELOPMENT_AUDIT`. Both the databases should have the same number of tables and columns.

My requirement is I have to check whether any column is missing in `CLX_DEVELOPMENT_AUDIT`.

Comment: show sample output and tabel strcture

Comment: SQL Server Data Tools, schema comparison. Low tech solution: script all tables using Management Studio, compare with your favorite diff tool. Your question doesn't make it clear if you need to compare *schema* or *data*, my remark pertains to the former. SSDT also has data comparison, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return columns from one database that are not present in the corresponding table of the other database:

```
WITH DB1 AS (
    SELECT objects.name AS TBL, columns.name AS COL
    FROM       CLX_DEVELOPMENT.sys.objects 
    INNER JOIN CLX_DEVELOPMENT.sys.columns ON objects.object_id = columns.object_id
    WHERE objects.type = 'U' -- user table
), DB2 AS (
    SELECT objects.name AS TBL, columns.name AS COL
    FROM       CLX_DEVELOPMENT_AUDIT.sys.objects 
    INNER JOIN CLX_DEVELOPMENT_AUDIT.sys.columns ON objects.object_id = columns.object_id
    WHERE objects.type = 'U' -- user table
)
SELECT DB1.TBL, DB1.COL
FROM DB1
LEFT JOIN DB2 ON DB1.TBL = DB2.TBL and DB1.COL = DB2.COL
WHERE DB2.TBL IS NULL
```

A more generic solution that generates a ***column diff*** of two databases is as follows:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM Database1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    UNION
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM Database2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
)
SELECT CTE.TABLE_NAME, CTE.COLUMN_NAME, CASE
    WHEN DB1.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL THEN 'DB2 Only'
    WHEN DB2.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL THEN 'DB1 Only'
    ELSE 'BOTH DB'
END AS [Present In]
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN Database1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS DB1 ON CTE.TABLE_NAME = DB1.TABLE_NAME AND CTE.COLUMN_NAME = DB1.COLUMN_NAME
LEFT JOIN Database2.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS DB2 ON CTE.TABLE_NAME = DB2.TABLE_NAME AND CTE.COLUMN_NAME = DB2.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE DB1.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL OR DB2.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you Salman A it is working but it is also showing view comparison

Comment: @ghayaz see revised answer.

Comment: Thank you Salman its working sorry it is showing both views as well as tables

Answer (score 0):

A good solution from dataedo. Link below:

https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/compare-tables-and-columns-in-two-databases

Script below peradventure link goes down:

```
select isnull(db1.table_name, db2.table_name) as [table],
       isnull(db1.column_name, db2.column_name) as [column],
       db1.column_name as database1, 
       db2.column_name as database2
from
(select schema_name(tab.schema_id) + '.' + tab.name as table_name, 
       col.name as column_name
   from [dataedo_6.0].sys.tables as tab
        inner join [dataedo_6.0].sys.columns as col
            on tab.object_id = col.object_id) db1
full outer join
(select schema_name(tab.schema_id) + '.' + tab.name as table_name, 
       col.name as column_name
   from [dataedo_7.0].sys.tables as tab
        inner join [dataedo_7.0].sys.columns as col
            on tab.object_id = col.object_id) db2
on db1.table_name = db2.table_name
and db1.column_name = db2.column_name
where (db1.column_name is null or db2.column_name is null)
order by 1, 2, 3
```

**Instruction**

Replace [dataedo_6.0] and [dataedo_7.0] with names of two of your databases (on SQL Server instance) that you'd like to compare.

You can also use the SQL Schema Comparison tool found in Visual Studio.